# How to write non-blocking code for twisted

Tags: multithreading, twisted

I have a connection which sends and receives data from a custom networking protocol through a serial port (yes, a serial port, an arduino, a rf24 card, etc etc).

I want to be able to do non-blocking code that queries the serial port waiting for response packets.
I already know I can use deferToThread when I'm using a 3rd party library I can't modify, but this is not the case, I can modify the code. I just want to know how you can implement your own non-blocking code that returns a Deferred and returns the result later.

for example:

1. send packet with ID 1 and wait for ACK with same ID
2. keep waiting while packet with ID 1 is not available in the received packets queue
3. if packet with ID 1 is found, return the result so the callbacks are "called" (sorry about the redundancy)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea is the following:

```
id_to_deferred_map = {}
def sendPacket(id, ...):
    ... # write to transport

    d = Deferred()        
    id_to_deferred_map[id] = d
    return d

# In protocol:
def packetReceived(id, ...):
    d = id_to_deferred_map[id]
    del id_to_deferred_map[id]
    d.callback()
```

This should give you an idea.  You simply have to maintain the state to remember the `id`'s and map them to the `Deferred`'s you've given out.  When you've got an packet back, you fetch the `Deferred` and trigger it with `.callback()`.

You have to fill in the code to write your packet, as well as parse arriving packets, fetch `id` and call `packetReceived`.

Comment: Good answer - maybe also worth giving an example of using the serial port transport in Twisted.